Can cutting board oils dissolve water soluable wood glues?
When I built my carving board I didn't realize I need to use a water resistant wood glue. I used Titebond original which is water soluable. I was recently told that most oils used in carving boards will dissolve water soluable glues in cutting board over time. Has anyone seen any evidence of this?  I asked Google and it just says that mineral oils and such can be used to remove glues.  Not the same thing.  I treated my carving board with 2 coats of fractionated coconut oil. After it had time to dry I used bees wax with a little mineral oil in it to wax it.  Will the fractionated coconut oil polamerize or can it remain fluid and dissolve the glue in the joints?
Thanks,
Mikey

I would think that washing your board would be a bigger problem, as that would actually use water.  or cutting fruit that gives off a lot of liquid

I've not heard about oils, but I do know that vinegar and other high acidic products like citrus fruits can sometimes cause issues with glue.
